# Make: Export["msft-2018-01-01-to-today.csv", FinancialData["MSFT", "Close","Jan. 1, 2018"]] export date column as date string "YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: export, date-and-time

Here is an example:

```
Export["~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03252018.csv", 
 FinancialData["NYSE:IVV", "Close", "Jan. 1, 2017"]]
```

The file contents then look like:

```
"{2017, 1, 3}",226.58
"{2017, 1, 4}",227.95
"{2017, 1, 5}",227.74
"{2017, 1, 6}",228.64
"{2017, 1, 9}",227.9
"{2017, 1, 10}",227.8
"{2017, 1, 11}",228.41
...
```

What I want is:

```
2017-01-03,226.58
```

I tried stuff like:

```
ds = SemanticImport[
  "~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03262018.csv"]
data = ds /. {d_String, 
    z__} :> {DateString[
     DateList[d], {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}], z}
Export["~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03262018-tweaked.csv", data];
```

or

```
ds = SemanticImport[
   "~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03262018.csv"];
data = ds /. {d_String, 
    z__} :> {StringReplace[StringReplace[StringTrim[d, ("{" | "}")], "," -> "-"]," " -> ""], z}
Export["~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03262018-tweaked.csv", data];
```

without success.

Update:

This one does it, but still leaves the quote marks on the date string which I don't want:

```
ds = Import[
   "~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03262018.csv", {"CSV", 
    "Dataset"}];
data = ds /. {d_String, 
     z__} :> {DateString[
      ToExpression[d], {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}], z};
Export["~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/ivv-01012017-03262018-tweaked.\
csv", data]
```

Result:

```
"2017-01-03",226.58
"2017-01-04",227.95
"2017-01-05",227.74
"2017-01-06",228.64
"2017-01-09",227.9
```

...

and I want

2017-01-03,226.58
...

Update (with help from J.M.needshelp):

Just packaging things up from answer below into a function and add headers to the exported file.

```
Clear[getTickerData];  

getTickerData[path_String, ticker_String, property_String, sinceDate_String, dateStringFormat_String] :=
Module[{raw},
  raw = FinancialData[ticker, property, sinceDate];
  Export[path, Prepend[MapAt[DateString[#, dateStringFormat] &, raw, {All, 1}] /. Missing[msg_] :> msg, {"Date", property}], "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]
];

getTickerData["~/EncryptedAlt3/src/trading/data/be:exx7-01012010-03272018.csv", "BE:EXX7", "Close", "Jan. 1, 2010", "ISODate"]
```

Comment: Do you want "2017-01-03,226.58" as a String?

Comment: @alancalvitti, Yes, I want that written to the export file as a string so that in the exported file it is simply data with no quotes, but yes you have the format correct.

Comment: A note: Hans used `ExportString[]` only so that you can easily preview the expected results in *Mathematica*. Since your actual application exports to a file, do this: `Export[path, MapAt[DateString[#, dateStringFormat] &, raw, {All, 1}] /. Missing[msg_] :> msg, "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]`. Adding the headers is a slight modification: `Export[path, Prepend[MapAt[DateString[#, dateStringFormat] &, raw, {All, 1}] /. Missing[msg_] :> msg, {"Date", property}], "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]`.

Comment: @J.M. thanks for revisiting this, your modification works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 
With @J.M.  suggestion/comment of much cleaner code

```
  raw = FinancialData["NYSE:IVV", "Close", "Jan. 1, 2017"];
 ExportString[MapAt[DateString[#, "ISODate"] &, raw, {All, 1}] /. Missing[msg_] :> msg, "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]
```

Below are just preliminary post

```
 ExportString[
 Map[Function[
   StringJoin[DateString[#[[1]], "ISODate" ], ",", 
    ToString[#[[2]] ]]],  
  FinancialData["NYSE:IVV", "Close", "Jan. 1, 2017"]], "Text"]
```

Using `ExportString` to get immediate output. Change to `Export[yourfilenamehere, ...]` if this meets your needs

This also works

```
    ExportString[
 Map[Function[{DateString[#[[1]], "ISODate" ], ToString[#[[2]] ]}],  
  FinancialData["NYSE:IVV", "Close", "Jan. 1, 2017"]], "CSV", 
 "TextDelimiters" -> ""]
```

Comment: Just `raw = FinancialData["NYSE:IVV", "Close", "Jan. 1, 2017"]; ExportString[MapAt[DateString[#, "ISODate"] &, raw, {All, 1}], "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]` suffices.

Comment: @J.M.  True Dat. Mostly pointing out ISODate. Don't recall which version it was introduced. Your version is cleaner. My overkill on the Close value was due to `Missing["NotAvailable"]` value might popup for some financial data.

Comment: @J.M. that is what I wanted. Make it an answer if you like and I'll accept it. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Joe, please accept Hans's answer instead, contingent on him editing his answer.

Comment: @Hans, I forgot to account for `Missing[]`, thanks for reminding! I guess something like `ExportString[MapAt[DateString[#, "ISODate"] &, raw, {All, 1}] /. Missing[msg_] :> msg, "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> ""]` should take care of it.

Comment: @J.M. Even better. Seems like `FinancialData[]` is very stable today I could not readily find a stock to test for `Missing[]`

Comment: @Hans, if you update per J.M.'s suggestion above, I'll accept yours. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @Joe Just updated